# What is the right way to simulate a dice rolling in Unity with a pre-determined outcome?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have made two dice as rigid bodies and now on application of random forces they give random outcomes. How should I make the dice roll to a predefined outcome?

Comment: Can you log the random force you apply, such that you can use the same force again to roll the same outcome?

Comment: that's very good. You can make a library of forces so you have many options for the same result and your game doesn't look like it's playing the same thing over and over.

Answer (score 2):

It would probably be easiest to use Unity's built in animation system to accomplish this.  Instead of spending so much time on making a library of forces to apply you would only need to do a total of six animations.  Then apply the animation which yields then number you want to each die.